# Sending JSON List Of Object to Spring MVC controller

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

I have an issue with sending a List Of Objects to Spring MVC controller .

The list of object is like this

```
[{"alias":"1",
  "rue":"Rue de la Senette",
  "codePostal":"78955",
  "ville":"Carrières-sous-Poissy",
  "rueComplement":""}]
```

And I send the above data with the following **AJAX** code:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType :'application/json',
    url : $("#clientForm-add").attr('action'),
    data : JSON.stringify(adresses.toArray()),
});
```

When I use this form of ajax, it worked for me and the format sended is as follow:

```
Request Payload :
[{"alias":"1",
  "rue":"Rue de la Senette",
  "codePostal":"78955",
  "ville":"Carrières-sous-Poissy",
  "rueComplement":""}]
```

Yes, even the above one is worked, when i send it like as follow:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType :'application/json',
    url : $("#clientForm-add").attr('action'),
    data : {adresseList : JSON.stringify(adresses.toArray())},
});
```

It doesn;t work for me. The sending data is look like

> listAdresse=%5B%7B%22alias%22%3A%221%22%2C%22rue%22%3A%22Rue+de+la+Senette%22%2C%22codePostal%22%3A%2278955%22%2C%22ville%22%3A%22Carri%C3%A8res-sous-Poissy%22%2C%22rueComplement%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D
>   Response Headersview source

And, It gave an error: **`400 bad request`**

Here, my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "creerlivraison/ajouterclientBD",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String ajouterClientBD(@RequestBody  Adresse[] listAdresse, Principal principal) {       
    for (Adresse adresse : listAdresse) {
        System.out.println(adresse);
    }   
    return "ok";
}
```

I want to know that "What is the difference between the two ajax request?", why the request payload is formatted when I wrap the data inside **the braquets {} and specify listAddress**.

**Here is screen capture:**

[image: Object Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> ## data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

In this instance,

- `JSON.stringify(adresses.toArray())` is string, just keep the JSON format.
- `{adresseList : JSON.stringify(adresses.toArray())}` is an object, so it is converted to a query string.